# In grub rescue, I cannot insmod normal

Tags: grubrescue

I am running only Ubuntu.I have tried a few "rescue" disks but had no luck. I can find linux partition,and I can do "set" and "preview" with success. When I try insmod normal, I get an error.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system. Are you booting in same mode as install is/was configured? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: HTTP://paste.Ubuntu.com/15472219/

Comment: Not showing hard drive at all?? Does BIOS see drive? Double check cables, connections etc. Also in Disks in live installer, and icon in upper right see if Smart Data shows drive and if drive is ok. Also can run tests of drive.

Answer (score 0):

OrdFred thank you for your help. I Tried the 2 rescue disks, but they didn't help. I opened the box and tried, as you suggested, but it didn't cure my problem. I tried Ubuntu live CD and it would sometimes freeze, then work, then freeze, and work.  I pulled the hard drive and installed in another machine. When I booted, the Live CD noticed an error on the hard drive. It asked if I wanted to fix it. I chose Y. The screen looked like the rescue disk, but gave me a "GRUB REPAIR"option. I chose Y. The screen froze and would not let go. I pressed the power button to turn the machine off, and the machine rebooted and put My desktop on my screen.
 I would suggest that anyone start with the Live CD, and ignore the Rescue Discs. 
My problem ended up being a driver or hardware issue. More than likely a hardware issue. 
Thanks again for all who helped.